# Given Three Points Compute Affine Transformation

Tags: matlab, image-processing, geometry, computer-vision, linear-algebra

I have two images and found three similar 2D points using a sift. I need to compute the affine transformation between the images. Unfortunately, I missed lecture and the information out there is a little dense for me. What would the general method be for computing this 2x3 matrix?

I have the matrix of points in a 2x3 matrix [x1 y1;x2 y2;x3 y3] but I am lost from there.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: @chappjc If only that was the same class xD

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Usually, an affine transormation of 2D points is experssed as

```
x' = A*x
```

Where `x` is a three-vector `[x; y; 1]` of original 2D location and `x'` is the transformed point. The affine matrix `A` is

```
A = [a11 a12 a13;
     a21 a22 a23;
       0   0   1]
```

This form is useful when `x` and `A` are *known* and you wish to recover `x'`.

However, you can express this relation in a different way.
Let

```
X = [xi yi 1  0  0  0;
      0  0 0 xi yi  1 ]
```

and `a` is a column vector

```
a = [a11; a12; a13; a21; a22; a23]
```

Then

```
X*a = [xi'; yi']
```

Holds for all pairs of corresponding points `x_i, x_i'`.

This alternative form is very useful when you know the correspondence between pairs of points and you wish to recover the paramters of `A`.
Stacking all your points in a large matrix `X` (two rows for each point) you'll have 2*n-by-6 matrix `X` multiplyied by 6-vector of unknowns `a` equals a 2*n-by-1 column vector of the stacked corresponding points (denoted by `x_prime`):

```
X*a = x_prime
```

Solving for `a`:

```
a = X \ x_prime
```

Recovers the parameters of `a` in a least-squares sense.

Good luck and stop skipping class!

Comment: Thank you! Life saver. I was unfortunately at an interview. If only his slides were as concise as your post :)

Comment: Great answer, and you took the high road; just one thing to add - a convenient way to go from `x`->`X` if `x` is `N-by-2` is with `X = kron(eye(2),[x ones(size(x,1),1)])`.  Also, for the `X` and `a` sizes you're using, you'll need `mldivide` to solve the system (`a = X \ x_prime`), unless you transpose both (`x_prime' / X'`).

Comment: @chappjc thanks for these important comments. I'll leave the `kron` part out - to let the poor student do some of his homework himself, but I'll correct the `mldivide` (I always get confused between them...)

Comment: Thanks for the review Shai. I have pairs of matches between two images and I had to implement RANSAC to find the best affine transform to describe the relationship between them...Couldn't quite remember how to set up the system. +1.

Answer (score 10):

Sorry for not using Matlab, but I only worked with Python a little bit. I think this code may help you (sorry for bad codestyle -- I'm mathematician, not programmer)

```py
import numpy as np
# input data
ins = [[1, 1], [2, 3], [3, 2]]  # <- points
out = [[0, 2], [1, 2], [-2, -1]] # <- mapped to
# calculations
l = len(ins)
B = np.vstack([np.transpose(ins), np.ones(l)])
D = 1.0 / np.linalg.det(B)
entry = lambda r,d: np.linalg.det(np.delete(np.vstack([r, B]), (d+1), axis=0))
M = [[(-1)**i * D * entry(R, i) for i in range(l)] for R in np.transpose(out)]
A, t = np.hsplit(np.array(M), [l-1])
t = np.transpose(t)[0]
# output
print("Affine transformation matrix:\n", A)
print("Affine transformation translation vector:\n", t)
# unittests
print("TESTING:")
for p, P in zip(np.array(ins), np.array(out)):
  image_p = np.dot(A, p) + t
  result = "[OK]" if np.allclose(image_p, P) else "[ERROR]"
  print(p, " mapped to: ", image_p, " ; expected: ", P, result)
```

This code demonstrates how to recover affine transformation as matrix and vector and tests that initial points are mapped to where they should. You can test this code with [Google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/welcome.ipynb), so you don't have to install anything. Probably, you can translate it to Matlab.

Regarding theory behind this code: it is based on equation presented in "[Beginner's guide to mapping simplexes affinely](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332971934_Workbook_on_mapping_simplexes_affinely)", matrix recovery is described in section "Recovery of canonical notation". The same authors published "[Workbook on mapping simplexes affinely](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332410209_Beginner%27s_guide_to_mapping_simplexes_affinely)" that contains many practical examples of this kind.

Answer (score 2):

for implementation purposes in OpenCV you can use [cv2.getAffineTransform](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga8f6d378f9f8eebb5cb55cd3ae295a999)

```
getAffineTransform() [1/2]

Mat cv::getAffineTransform  (   const Point2f   src[],
    const Point2f   dst[] 
)   

Python:

cv.getAffineTransform(  src, dst    ) ->    retval
```

Answer (score 1):

This is for anyone who wants to do it in C. The algorithm is based on this [MathStackExchange post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3628534/efficiently-solving-a-2d-affine-transformation/4207933#4207933). The author shows how to use Gauss-Jordan elimination to find the formula for the Affine transformation coefficients,

```
/*
*Function: Affine Solver
*Role: Finds Affine Transforming mapping (X,Y) to (X',Y')
*Input: double array[A,B,C,D,E,F], 
*   int array[X-Coordinates], int array[Y-Coordinates],
*   int array[X'-Coordinates],int array[Y'-Coordinates]
*Output:void - Fills double array[A,B,C,D,E,F]
*/

void AffineSolver(double *AtoF, int *X, int *Y, int *XP, int *YP)
{
    AtoF[0] = (double)(XP[1]*Y[0] - XP[2]*Y[0] - XP[0]*Y[1] + XP[2]*Y[1] + XP[0]*Y[2] -XP[1]*Y[2]) / 
          (double)(X[1]*Y[0] - X[2]*Y[0] - X[0]*Y[1] + X[2]*Y[1] + X[0]*Y[2] - X[1]*Y[2]);
          
    AtoF[1] = (double)(XP[1]*X[0] - XP[2]*X[0] - XP[0]*X[1] + XP[2]*X[1] + XP[0]*X[2] -XP[1]*X[2]) / 
          (double)(-X[1]*Y[0] + X[2]*Y[0] + X[0]*Y[1] - X[2]*Y[1] - X[0]*Y[2] +X[1]*Y[2]);
          
    AtoF[2] = (double)(YP[1]*Y[0] - YP[2]*Y[0] - YP[0]*Y[1] + YP[2]*Y[1] + YP[0]*Y[2] -YP[1]*Y[2]) / 
          (double)(X[1]*Y[0] - X[2]*Y[0] - X[0]*Y[1] + X[2]*Y[1] + X[0]*Y[2] - X[1]*Y[2]);
          
    AtoF[3] = (double)(YP[1]*X[0] - YP[2]*X[0] - YP[0]*X[1] + YP[2]*X[1] + YP[0]*X[2] -YP[1]*X[2]) / 
          (double)(-X[1]*Y[0] + X[2]*Y[0] + X[0]*Y[1] - X[2]*Y[1] - X[0]*Y[2] +X[1]*Y[2]);
          
    AtoF[4] = (double)(XP[2]*X[1]*Y[0] - XP[1]*X[2]*Y[0]-XP[2]*X[0]*Y[1] + XP[0]*X[2]*Y[1]+
           XP[1]*X[0]*Y[2] - XP[0]*X[1]*Y[2]) / 
          (double)(X[1]*Y[0] - X[2]*Y[0] - X[0]*Y[1] + X[2]*Y[1] + X[0]*Y[2] - X[1]*Y[2]);
          
    AtoF[5] = (double)(YP[2]*X[1]*Y[0] - YP[1]*X[2]*Y[0]-YP[2]*X[0]*Y[1] + YP[0]*X[2]*Y[1] + YP[1]*X[0]*Y[2] -            YP[0]*X[1]*Y[2]) / 
          (double)(X[1]*Y[0] - X[2]*Y[0] - X[0]*Y[1] + X[2]*Y[1] + X[0]*Y[2] - X[1]*Y[2]);
}

/*
*Function: PrintMatrix
*Role: Prints 2*3 matrix as //a b e
                //c d f
*Input: double array[ABCDEF]
*Output: voids
*/

void PrintMatrix(double *AtoF)
{
    printf("a = %f ",AtoF[0]);
    printf("b = %f ",AtoF[1]);
    printf("e = %f\n",AtoF[4]);
    printf("c = %f ",AtoF[2]);
    printf("d = %f ",AtoF[3]);
    printf("f = %f ",AtoF[5]);
}

int main()
{
/*Test*/
/*Find transform mapping (0,10),(0,0),(10,0) to (0,5)(0,0)(5,0)*/
/*Expected Output*/
//a = 0.500000 b = 0.000000 e = -0.000000
//c = -0.000000 d = 0.500000 f = -0.000000
/*Test*/
    double *AtoF = calloc(6, sizeof(double));
    int  X[] = { 0, 0,10};
    int  Y[] = {10, 0, 0};
    int XP[] = { 0, 0, 5};
    int YP[] = { 5, 0, 0};
    AffineSolver(AtoF,X,Y,XP,YP);
    PrintMatrix(AtoF);
    free(AtoF);
    return 0;
}
```