# Fill the circular paths in image

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation, edge-detection

I have many images consisting of circles(varying from 1 to 4) in each image. I am trying to get a clear circle images by filling the missed pixels along the circle path.

I have tried Hough-transform, but its parameters are image specific: for each image I have to change the parameters.   With this problem I am unable keep them in a single for loop.

Please provide some method to do it. Thanks[image: 1. contains one circles]

[image: 2. contains two circles]

[image: 3. contains three circles]

[image: 4. contains four circles]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[`imfindcircles`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfindcircles.html)  Does not work**
The most "natural" way to approach this problem is to use Matlab's [`imfindcircles`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfindcircles.html). However, that function assume the circles in the image are "full", yet in your examples you only have the (incomplete) boundaries of the circles, thus `imfindcircles` cannot be directly applied to your data.

**Alternative Approach**
You can use [`ransac`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/ransac.html) to fit circles to your data. Fit one circle at a time to as many points as you can, terminate when there are too few points left that fit no circle at all.

To use [RanSac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus) you basically need to implement two methods:

1. **Model fitting method**, `fitFcn`, Given a small sample of your points - fit a circle to them.
2. **Distance to model method**, `distFcn`,  Given a circle ("model") find the distance of each point to that circle.

Once you have these two methods, RanSac operates roughly like:
- randomly sample very few points
- use `fitFcn` to fit a circle to these sampled points
- use `distFcn` to compute the distance of all points to estimated circle
- if enough points are close to the circle, accept this circle and remove all point that "belongs" to that circle
- terminate if no circle was found or not enough "unexplained" points

This can be easily implemented in Matlab.

First consider **`fitFcn`**: we need a function that compute (`cx`, `cy`, `r`) - the three parameters of a 2D circle (center and radii). Given a point (`x`, `y`) it fits a circle iff

```matlab
(x - cx)^2 + (y - cy)^2 = r^2
```

We can write this equation as a linear relation between known points (`x`, `y`) and unknown circle (`cx`, `cy`, `r`) in the following manner

```matlab
[-2*x, -2*y, 1] [ cx ; 
                  cy ;                 = [-x^2-y^2]
                  cx^2 + cy^2 - r^2 ]
```

Using a least squares estimation (in a similar manner as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22954521/1714410)), we can recover the circle parameters given enough points (at least 3) on the circle

This is how the code actually looks like

```matlab
function crc = fit_circle(xy)  % xy is n-by-2 matrix of point coordinates
% fit in least squares sens
x = xy(:, 1);
y = xy(:, 2);
X = [-2*x, -2*y, ones(size(x))]; 
Y = -x.^2 - y.^2;
crc = (X\Y).';  % least squares solution
r2 = -crc(3) +crc(1).^2 + crc(2).^2; 
if r2 <= 0
    crc(3) = 0;
else    
    crc(3) = sqrt(r2);
end
% output crc is a 3 vector (cx, cy, r)
```

Now that we can fit a circle to points, we need to compute the distance using **`distFcn`** that is quite simple

```matlab
function dst = distFcn(crc, xy)
% how good a fit circle for points
x = xy(:, 1) - crc(1);
y = xy(:, 2) - crc(2);
dst = abs(sqrt(x.^2 + y.^2) - crc(3));
```

Putting it all together with matlab's [`ransac`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/ransac.html):

```matlab
function circles = find_circles(bw)
% parameters
sample_size = 4;
max_distance = 10;
min_num_points_in_circle = 50;

[y, x] = find(bw > max(bw(:))/2);  % all edges in the image

circles = {};
counter = 0;
while numel(x) > 10 * sample_size && counter < 10
    try
        [circle, inlierIdx] = ransac([x, y], @fit_circle, @distFcn, ...
            sample_size, max_distance);
    catch
        break
    end
    % refit using only inliers
    circle = fit_circle([x(inlierIdx) y(inlierIdx)]);
    dst = distFcn(circle, [x y]);
    founfit = dst < max_distance;
    if sum(founfit) > min_num_points_in_circle
        % this model fits enough points
        circles{end+1} = circle;
        x(founfit) = [];
        y(founfit) = [];
    else
        counter = counter + 1;
    end    
end
circles = vertcat(circles{:});
```

And the output of this function on your data is (using [`viscircles`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/viscircles.html) to plot the circles):
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]